# Rails - ping user without authenticating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

So I'm writing a Facebook clone for a school project using Rails and I need some way to keep track of which users are logged in. At the moment, I'm a bit time-pressed, so I decided just to update the User model every time they visit a page with a last_seen attribute.

Problem is, the user model requires revalidation to successfully update_attributes. So I'm wondering two things:

1. Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?
2. If not (or if it would take too long) is there a way to bypass the validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to 1.: I cant give you an exact answer but I think itwould be better to deal with this problem using a javascript on the clientside with a timer that sends an ajax request all xxx secounds and an action that receives this requests and saves it in a seperate table associated with the `User`.

to 2.: Yes there are some ways to bypass validations The most pragmatic way is to bypass the `:validate => false` option when saving the object but then you can use `update_attributes`:

```
object.save(:validate => false)
```

So there is also the possibility to use conditional validations that are only used when a specific condition is complyed. There is a railscast about that => http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations .